# Add a new organisation into an existing Hyperledger fabric network, based on the 1.1.0-preview (mainly, the fifth organisation)

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger

I followed the tutorial from the https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DKuGU5CYV_E&t=5s, and successfully added the third organisation into the existing fabric network. Also, I tried the forth. However, When I tried to add the fifth organisation into this network following the steps(https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/channel_update.html), when I running the command "peer channel update -f org5_update_in_envelope.pb -c $CHANNEL_NAME -o orderer.example.com:7050 --tls --cafile $ORDERER_CA", it mentioned the error about 3 policies, and  one policy is remaining. I checked the Order log, it shows 
[error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LsVNn.jpg). I am using the command "peer chaincode upgrade -o orderer.example.com:7050 --tls $CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED --cafile $ORDERER_CA -C $CHANNEL_NAME -n mycc -v 2.0 -c '{"Args":["init","a","90","b","210"]}' -P "OR ('Org1MSP.member','Org2MSP.member','Org3MSP.member')"
to change the endorsement policy. I think it is an issue about the "MSP policy". Anyone has met the same issue?

Comment: Can you clarify? Is the error log shown from peer channel update -f org5 or from peer code chaincode upgrade?

Comment: Hello, It is from the command "peer channel update -f org5", I followed the step, so it is should be in the Org2 environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you need to run the channel update using the crypto from an admin for either Org3 or Org4. You have signatures for Org 1 and Org2. But you need 3 of Orgs1-4.

Follow the steps for

Export the Org2 environment variables:

except change everything to either Org3 or Org4 admin. Then run the upgrade command.

Or you could sign it as an admin from Org3 or Org4 and then any admin can upgrade it.

Comment: Hi, jworthington! Thank you very much for your help. you are right, I need to sign the org5_update_in_envelope.pb from Org3 or Org4, AND I have successfully add the Org5.

Answer (score 0):

You have to run peer channel signconfigtx in your Previous Organizations. Then Only you can update your channel.

### You have to run the following command repeatedly for each organization:

```
"Loop Org1,org2,org3,org4"

docker cp org5_update_in_envelope.pb peer0.org1.example-swarm.com:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/

docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/configtx/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp" -e "CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/configtx/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt" peer0.org1.example-swarm.com peer channel signconfigtx -f org5_update_in_envelope.pb

docker cp peer0.org1.example-swarm.com:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/org5_update_in_envelope.pb org5_update_in_envelope.pb 

"End Loop"
```

### Finally you can run :

```
docker cp org5_update_in_envelope.pb peer0.org1.example-swarm.com:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/

docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/configtx/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp" -e "CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/configtx/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt" peer0.org1.example-swarm.com peer channel update -f org5_update_in_envelope.pb -c $CHANNEL_NAME -o orderer.example.com:7050
```